# Dynamic Action filter not Correctly Filtering by User Role

Tags: filters, lightning-record-page, dynamic-actions

I'm trying to hide the 'Edit CFR' button from all users with the 'NOW Engineer' Role, but with the following filter the button is still available to users who have the role:

[image]

Here is the Role in Question:
[image]

I've also tried matching by Role Developer Name not equal to NOW_Engineer, with no luck.

I've used similar logic to match a different Role which worked successfully, which leads me to believe I'm missing something.

Comment: dynamic actions using developerName works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user I was testing with did not have the 'Allow user to view roles and role hierarchy' System permission enabled. Apparently without the user having access to view roles the system role filter will not work, so this setting needs to be enabled for Record Page Role filters to work correctly.